# Merge/Combine two header rows

Tags: powerquery

I have ever-changing header rows for a list of 1000+ shops (column order is changing) and I need to combine the first two rows into one header.

This is the simplified example table with 3 distinct shops and 4 weeks of data (the real data is > 40000 rows with 88 columns each)

| Column0 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column8 | Column11 | Index | Shopbrand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product | 00/00182 | Week | ProductA | ProductA | ProductA | ProductB | ProductB | ProductB | 359 | ShopBrand0 |
| Datatype | 00/00182 |  | Sc Amount | Sc Value | Sc Profit | Sc Amount | Sc Value | Sc Profit | 360 | ShopBrand0 |
| Week | 00/00182 | 202201 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 361 | ShopBrand0 |
| Week | 00/00182 | 202202 | 4 | 11,96 | 4 |  |  |  | 362 | ShopBrand0 |
| Week | 00/00182 | 202203 | 5 | 14,95 | 8 |  |  |  | 363 | ShopBrand0 |
| Week | 00/00182 | 202204 | 1 | 6,49 | 1,5 |  |  |  | 364 | ShopBrand0 |
| Product | 00/00205 | Week | ProductA | ProductA | ProductA | ProductB | ProductB | ProductB | 400 | ShopBrand0 |
| Datatype | 00/00205 |  | Sc Amount | Sc Value | Sc Profit | Sc Amount | Sc Value | Sc Profit | 401 | ShopBrand0 |
| Week | 00/00205 | 202201 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 402 | ShopBrand0 |
| Week | 00/00205 | 202202 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 403 | ShopBrand0 |
| Week | 00/00205 | 202203 | 1 | 5,09 | 0,79 | 1 | 6,49 | 1,5 | 404 | ShopBrand0 |
| Week | 00/00205 | 202204 | 0 | 0 | -19,19 | 1 | 6,49 | -10 | 405 | ShopBrand0 |
| Product | 00/09002 | Week | ProductA | ProductA | ProductA | ProductB | ProductB | ProductB | 42557 | ShopBrand1 |
| Datatype | 00/09002 |  | Sc Amount | Sc Value | Sc Profit | Sc Amount | Sc Value | Sc Profit | 42558 | ShopBrand1 |
| Week | 00/09002 | 202201 | 2 | 11,1 | 3,22 | 4 | 23,36 | 5,88 | 42559 | ShopBrand1 |
| Week | 00/09002 | 202202 |  |  |  | 5 | 25,45 | 3,95 | 42560 | ShopBrand1 |
| Week | 00/09002 | 202203 | 3 | 14,97 | 2,09 | 2 | 8,98 | 0,48 | 42561 | ShopBrand1 |
| Week | 00/09002 | 202204 | 2 | 8,98 | 0,48 | 7 | 33,83 | 3,88 | 42562 | ShopBrand1 |

Note that every shop-id (column1) has TWO header rows, where the "product + datatype" (column3 onwards) need to be combined.

I can group by shop two get individual tables (real data approx 1200 shops), but who can I efficiently combine the two rows so that e.g. in Column3 I do get "ProductA : Sc Amount".

Note that due to the data source ProductA is NOT always in Column3, but for some shops it might be a different product that comes first, so I cannot simply take a fixed header for all the shops, I need to go through it for each shop individually.

This is the first part of the code with a bit more table data (no row combining, just grouping)

```
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText(
"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",
 BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)),
 let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column0 = _t, Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t, Column3 = _t, Column4 = _t, Column5 = _t, Column6 = _t, Column8 = _t, Column11 = _t, Index = _t, Shopbrand = _t]),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Column1"}, 
{{"storetables", 
each _, type table [Column0=nullable text, Column1=nullable text, Column2=nullable text, Column3=nullable text, Column4=nullable text, Column5=nullable text, Column6=nullable text, Column8=nullable text, Column11=nullable text, Index=nullable text, Shopbrand=nullable text]}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Basically I need a more efficient version, than what I already came up with. On smaller test-data I did already cobble together this code fragment inspired by https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-Help/m-p/381272 but on the real 40000+ rows table this did still run aufer 100 minutes without feedback, so I stopped it.

```
        // Converts a list of records, into a table
        Table.TransformRows(
            // Creates a list by applying the transform operation to each row in table
            #"table",
            (row) =>
                let
                    // Keep only Cols that need transforming => remove the following:
                    TransformTheseColumns = List.RemoveItems(
                        // Removes all occurrences of the given values in the list2 from list1
                        Record.FieldNames(row),
                        //Returns the names of the fields in the record
                        {"Column0","Column1","Column2","Index","Shopbrand"}
                    ),
                    Transforms = List.Transform(
                        TransformTheseColumns,
                        (name) =>
                            {name,(cell) =>
                                    if Text.Contains(row[Column0],"Product") 
                                    then
                                        cell
                                            & " : "
                                            & Table.FirstValue(
                                                Table.SelectColumns(
                                                    Table.SelectRows(
                                                        #"table-empty-rows-removed",
                                                        each
                                                            [Index] = row[Index] + 1
                                                    ),
                                                    name
                                                )
                                            )
                                    else
                                        cell
                            }
                    )
                in
                    Record.TransformFields(
                        // Returns a record after applying transformations specified
                        row, Transforms
                    )
        )
    )
```

Another idea I came up with was to combine just the row headers, which leaves me with a list, but I don't know how to re-add this as the first row into the table. But it might be a good start for a more efficient solution, i.e. running through all the grouped tables, extracting the first two rows, combining them and sticking them back into the table.

```
= List.Transform(  List.Zip( Table.ToRows ( just_two_headers )), each Lines.ToText( _, " : "))
```

outcome should be something like this (for each shop):
[image]

Comment: A screenshot of your desired outcome would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

To combine row1/row2 and make that the column names of all columns:

```
#"NewNames" = Table.AddColumn(Table.Transpose(Table.FirstN(Source,2)), "Custom", each Text.Trim([Column1]&":"&[Column2]))[Custom],
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns( Table.Skip(Source,2), List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Source ), #"NewNames" } ) )
```

or same as above, but then specify the first 3 column names individually as special cases:

```
FirstFew={"A","B","C"},
#"NewNames1" = Table.AddColumn(Table.Transpose(Table.FirstN(Source,2)), "Custom", each Text.Trim([Column1]&":"&[Column2]))[Custom],
#"NewNames" = FirstFew & List.Skip(#"NewNames1",List.Count(FirstFew)),
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns( Table.Skip(Source,2), List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Source ), #"NewNames" } ) )
```

**updated answer**

I don't understand why you are bothering with the grouping.  It seems you can do it with one shot, then apply a filter to pull out the bad rows

```
<snip>
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Source, {"Index","Shopbrand","Column0","Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5","Column6","Column8","Column11" }),
NewNames = Table.AddColumn(Table.Transpose(Table.FirstN(  #"Reordered Columns", 2)),"Custom",each Text.Trim([Column1]& " : "& [Column2]))[Custom],
rename_headers = Table.RenameColumns(Table.Skip(  #"Reordered Columns", 2),List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(  #"Reordered Columns"),{"Index","Shopbrand","delete-able","shop-nr","Week"}& List.Skip(NewNames, 5)})),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(rename_headers, "shop-nr", "shop-nr - Copy"),
#"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"shop-nr", "Index", "Shopbrand", "delete-able", "shop-nr - Copy", "Week"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns2", each ([#"delete-able"] = "Week"))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks again @horseyride. I adapted this further and will add my final solution to my post above

Answer (score 1):

This is my final solution incorporating @horseyrides answer above.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(
        Json.Document(
            Binary.Decompress(
                Binary.FromText(
                    "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",
                    BinaryEncoding.Base64
                ),
                Compression.Deflate
            )
        ),
        let
            _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]            )
        in
            type table [Column0 = _t,Column1 = _t,Column2 = _t,Column3 = _t,Column4 = _t,Column5 = _t,Column6 = _t,Column8 = _t,Column11 = _t,Index = _t,
                Shopbrand = _t
            ]
    ),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(
        Source, {"Index","Shopbrand","Column0","Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5","Column6","Column8","Column11" }
    ),
    // Grouping and expanding based on this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73800993/1440255
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
        #"Reordered Columns",
        {
            "Column1"
        },
        {{
                "storetables",
                each
                    _,
                type table [Column0 = nullable text,Column1 = nullable text,Column2 = nullable text,Column3 = nullable text,Column4 = nullable text,Column5 = nullable text,Column6 = nullable text,Column8 = nullable text,Column11 = nullable text,Index = nullable text,Shopbrand = nullable text]
         }}
    ),
    // helper only for debuging to see one of the stores tables
    #"00/00182" = #"Grouped Rows"{[Column1 = "00/00182"]}[storetables],
    // go through all tables in storetables and join the first two rows and use them as new headers
    #"newshop" = Table.TransformColumns(
        #"Grouped Rows",
        {
            {
                "storetables",
                each
                    let
                        // join the first two rows with " : "
                        NewNames = Table.AddColumn(
                            Table.Transpose(Table.FirstN(_, 2)),
                            "Custom",
                            each Text.Trim([Column1]& " : "& [Column2])
                        )[Custom],
                        // rename the headers, but keep the first 5 from the fixed list below
                        rename_headers = Table.RenameColumns(
                            Table.Skip(_, 2),
                            List.Zip(
                                {Table.ColumnNames(_),
                                    {
                                        "Index","Shopbrand","delete-able","shop-nr","Week"
                                    }
                                        & List.Skip(NewNames, 5)
                                }
                            )
                        )
                    in
                        rename_headers
            }
        }
    ),
    // Epand all storetables back into one beautiful table
    #"expand storetables" =
        let
            ColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(
                Table.Combine(#"newshop"[storetables])
            ),
            ExpandColumns = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
                #"newshop",
                "storetables",
                ColumnNames
            )
        in
            ExpandColumns
in
    #"expand storetables"
```

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Transpose table
2. Concatenate first 2 columns
3. Transpose back

Comment: but how would I loop this, when I have this structure after the step "grouped rows":

| Column1  | storetables |
|----------|-------------|
| 00/00182 | [table]     |
| 00/00205 | [table]     |
| 00/09002 | [table]     |

Note: real data has about 1200 stores (i.e. lines, ie. separate tables).